# How to get a List type with type arguments in Java annotation processor

Tags: java, kotlin, javac, annotation-processing

Let's say I have a property

```
@MyAnnotation
class Foo {
    var bar: List<String> = emptyList()
}
```

And I'm writing an annotation processor for the code above:

```
class AnnotationProcessor : AbstractProcessor() {


    override fun getSupportedAnnotationTypes(): MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf(...)

    @KotlinPoetMetadataPreview
    override fun process(annotations: MutableSet<out TypeElement>?, roundEnv: RoundEnvironment?
): Boolean {

        val barPropType: TypeMirror = (roundEnv!!.getElementsAnnotatedWith(Command::class.java) as TypeElement)
            .kotlinProperties
            .first()
            .type


        return true
    } 
}
```

I want to now verify that the type of the property is assignable from `List<String>`

A solution I was able to find is to use the [isAssignable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#isAssignable-javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror-javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror-) method avaliable in `TypeUtils`, but in order to do that I would need an instance of TypeMirror for List, which I was not able to find a way to do. I can get an instance of List and perform an erasure to obtain a `TypeMirror` of raw type, which will not help me though as it is assignable to any `List<>`, a `List<Integer>` for example:

```
val listType = processingEnv.elementUtils.getTypeElement(List::class.java.name).asType()

println((listType as DeclaredType).typeArguments) // E

println(processingEnv.typeUtils.isAssignable(barPropType, listType)) // false

        println(processingEnv.typeUtils.isAssignable( // true, but also true when barPropType is List<Integer>
            processingEnv.typeUtils.erasure(barPropType),
            listType,
        ))
```

[This talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Dlo8OSwzaI) proposes a following solution:

```
  /**
   * Get the type parameter for a {@link Collection}.
   * @param type a parameterized collection type
   * @return the type of elements in the collection
   */
  private DeclaredType getCollectionType(TypeMirror type) {
    if (type != null && typeUtils().isAssignable(type, collectionType.type)) {
      // This is a bit of a hack; to work properly, we should walk up the inheritance hierarchy, tracking type
      // parameters as we go. For example, if the type in question is StringList, which implements List<String>,
      // then this code would not work.
      List<? extends TypeMirror> typeArguments = ((DeclaredType) type).getTypeArguments();
      return (DeclaredType) typeArguments.get(0);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

[full code](https://github.com/irobertson/jpa-annotation-processor)

For my project, I would need that "proper" solution, but I don't know how to implement it. I've done something like this:

```
fun TypeElement.allSuperInterfaces(env: ProcessingEnvironment): List<TypeMirror> {
    val result: MutableList<TypeMirror> = mutableListOf(this.asType())
    result.addAll(interfaces)

    var toCheckFurther = interfaces
    while(toCheckFurther.isNotEmpty()) {

        toCheckFurther = toCheckFurther
            .mapNotNull { env.typeUtils.asElement(it) as? TypeElement }
            .flatMap { it.interfaces }
            .toMutableList()

        result.addAll(toCheckFurther)

    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem with this is that during conversion from the `TypeMirror` to `TypeElement` information about the actual type argument is lost:

```
((barPropType as DeclaredType).asElement() as TypeElement)
            .allSuperInterfaces(processingEnv)
            .forEach(::println)
```

outputs:

```
java.util.List<E>
java.util.Collection<E>
java.lang.Iterable<E>
```

But at the same time it seems like this conversion needs to take place as there is no way of obtaining the implemented interfaces from the TypeMirror (at least that I am aware of).

What is the proper way to implement this solution involving walking up the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: so you have a class with a certain annotation `@MyAnnotation` and you want to write a processor that does exactly what? that all variables in that class are assignable to `List<String>`? sorry, but I am confused (mainly because I know very little kotlin)

Comment: I just want to verify exactly what type of `List<>`, a List<String> for example, a certain TypeMirror is. This type mirror is represented `barPropType` in examples above.

Answer (score -2):

You need to override AbstractProcessor [init-Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#init-javax.annotation.processing.ProcessingEnvironment-). There you will get "processingEnv" parameter which you can use to initilaize TypeMirror for List-class,
which you can use later with *isAssignable*.

In java it will looks like that:

```
public final class MyProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    private TypeMirror listTM;

    @Override public void init(ProcessingEnvironment processingEnv) {
        super.init(processingEnv);
        listTM = processingEnv.getElementUtils().getTypeElement(List.class.getName()).asType();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quoting my question: "A solution I was able to find is to use the isAssignable method avaliable in TypeUtils, but in order to do that I would need an instance of TypeMirror for List, which I was not able to find a way to do. I can get an instance of List and perform an erasure to obtain a TypeMirror of raw type, which will not help me though as it is assignable to any List<>, a List<Integer> for example:". Please specify exactly how can i use `isAssignable` to determine generic type of a field.

Comment: would not `Types.getTypeElement(Listclass.getName())` do that?